# Prevent Firefox Search Bar from Showing Last Entered Search

Tags: firefox, history

Is there any way to make the search bar become cleared again whenever you search for something?

(Note: This is about the search *bar* -- I do **NOT** want to clear my entire history just to get rid of this!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clearing your saved form data.  Most browsers have an option for this when clearing browser history and will let you choose what you want to clear (i.e form history) while still preserving other things (i.e browsing history, cookies, etc)

If it's something that you deal with often, try using another browser profile where you can set the preferences to delete your history when you close the browser.

Or in Firefox, try using private browsing for activities that necessitate eliminating the search history :)

---

IF you want to go the addon way, try [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-clear-search-box/)

Comment: (1) "Try clearing your saved form data" --> I specifically said I **only** wanted to clear the search **BAR**, *automatically* (not manually).
(2) "Try using another browser profile where you can set the preferences to delete your history when you close the browser." --> Thanks, but I specifically said that, above.
(3) "Try using private browsing" --> Thrice did I say I *just* wanted the search **BAR** to not keep the history. :)

Comment: @Lambert - Get a programming book and start cracking.  You could write a browser add-on to do what you want to do.... actually that's a good point.  Try doing a search for an add-on that does what you're looking for.  All joking aside, if it's a problem a lot of people encounter, you're likely to find that someone developed something that will do the trick.  Good luck.

Comment: Now *this* is a better answer (although the one I wasn't hoping for)!! :)
I am a programmer, so doing that won't be too difficult, just requires some determination. :]

Comment: @Lambert - Could also be kinda fun.  It would be interesting to see what you come up with :)  Does this help.  Check it out:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-clear-search-box/

Comment: WOW, +1... that's EXACTLY what I want, except that it's not compatible with my version. But that's a different issue -- I'll mark this as the answer, since it's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad I Was able to help!  Maybe you could contact the developer and he/she could tell you what would need to be done to make it compatible :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an addon that can do this: [SearchLoad Options](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/searchload-options/).

Comment: +1 Wow, nice one. Sorry I already accepted an answer, but this seems to be great too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is already answered, but try this (Looks like more easier to me):

- Tools/Options/Privacy tab.
- select the option "none" for "When using the address bar, sugest:"

(Fast translation from firefox spanish)

Comment: The address bar and the search bar are two different things.